# How to convert CM_POWER_DATA to Ctypes structure?

Tags: python, ctypes

How to convert CM_POWER_DATA to Ctypes structure ?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/ns-wdm-cm_power_data_s

My problem is that the `DEVICE_POWER_STATE` data type doesn't know how to convert

```
typedef struct CM_Power_Data_s {
  ULONG              PD_Size;
  DEVICE_POWER_STATE PD_MostRecentPowerState;
  ULONG              PD_Capabilities;
  ULONG              PD_D1Latency;
  ULONG              PD_D2Latency;
  ULONG              PD_D3Latency;
  DEVICE_POWER_STATE PD_PowerStateMapping[POWER_SYSTEM_MAXIMUM];
  SYSTEM_POWER_STATE PD_DeepestSystemWake;
} CM_POWER_DATA, *PCM_POWER_DATA;
```

Below is the python code

```
class CM_Power_Data_s(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = (('PD_Size', w.ULONG),
                ('PD_MostRecentPowerState', DEVICE_POWER_STATE), 
                ('PD_Capabilities', w.ULONG), 
                ('PD_D1Latency', w.ULONG)
                ('PD_D2Latency', w.ULONG)                , 
                ('PD_D3Latency', w.ULONG)
                ('PD_PowerStateMapping[POWER_SYSTEM_MAXIMUM]', DEVICE_POWER_STATE)
                ('PD_DeepestSystemWake', DEVICE_POWER_STATE) )
```

`NameError: name 'DEVICE_POWER_STATE' is not defined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself as follows
If necessary, please refer to the following

```
import ctypes as ct
from ctypes import wintypes as w

ENUM = ct.c_int 
POWER_SYSTEM_MAXIMUM = 7

class _SYSTEM_POWER_STATE(ENUM):
    PowerSystemUnspecified = 0
    PowerSystemWorking = 1
    PowerSystemSleeping1 = 2
    PowerSystemSleeping2 = 3
    PowerSystemSleeping3 = 4
    PowerSystemHibernate = 5
    PowerSystemShutdown = 6
    PowerSystemMaximum = 7


SYSTEM_POWER_STATE = _SYSTEM_POWER_STATE
PSYSTEM_POWER_STATE = ct.POINTER(_SYSTEM_POWER_STATE)
   
class _DEVICE_POWER_STATE(ENUM):
    PowerDeviceUnspecified = 0
    PowerDeviceD0 = 1
    PowerDeviceD1 = 2
    PowerDeviceD2 = 3
    PowerDeviceD3 = 4
    PowerDeviceMaximum = 5   

DEVICE_POWER_STATE = _DEVICE_POWER_STATE   
        
PDCAP_D0_SUPPORTED = 0x00000001
PDCAP_D1_SUPPORTED = 0x00000002
PDCAP_D2_SUPPORTED = 0x00000004
PDCAP_D3_SUPPORTED = 0x00000008
PDCAP_WAKE_FROM_D0_SUPPORTED = 0x00000010
PDCAP_WAKE_FROM_D1_SUPPORTED = 0x00000020
PDCAP_WAKE_FROM_D2_SUPPORTED = 0x00000040
PDCAP_WAKE_FROM_D3_SUPPORTED = 0x00000080
PDCAP_WARM_EJECT_SUPPORTED = 0x00000100
        
class CM_Power_Data_s(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('PD_Size', w.ULONG),
        ('PD_MostRecentPowerState', DEVICE_POWER_STATE),
        ('PD_Capabilities', w.ULONG),
        ('PD_D1Latency', w.ULONG),
        ('PD_D2Latency', w.ULONG),
        ('PD_D3Latency', w.ULONG),
        ('PD_PowerStateMapping', DEVICE_POWER_STATE *
                                 POWER_SYSTEM_MAXIMUM),
        ('PD_DeepestSystemWake', SYSTEM_POWER_STATE),
        ]
    CM_POWER_DATA = CM_Power_Data_s
    PCM_POWER_DATA = ct.POINTER(CM_Power_Data_s)
```